# How do I re-enable Quack Overflow?

Tags: support, bug, april-fools, quack-overflow

I was very pleased to find the addition of a yellow duck to the stack overflow pages, that promised to help. 
Unfortunately I told it that I would hate it not considering the impact my behaviour would have on the life of the duck: I made it cry.

Now I would like to bring it back to say sorry. But how do I do that?

Comment: Treat your rubber ducky well ...